# Blueimp fileupload - select files in one window, upload in another?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I would like to have a page in our webapp that lets you select files using the blueimp fileupload plugin and set some properties on the files (also sent in the message).

When you click upload, I would like the uploading to take place in a popup and give the user the freedom to navigate away in the main window. The entire form/files/etc would move to the popup.

I'm aware of methods to do the uploading in the main window and use the popup for progress, but it seems that you cannot offload the uploading to the popup as well. The main issue seems to be passing the file objects to the other window, due to general security issues passing file objects around.

Any ideas? It would have to support IE8+ which might further complicate things. I have a feeling i'm out of luck.